# How to check the records with some value must exist in SQL server 2014?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table "**CarParties**" having columns `car_id(FK)`, `partyId(FK)` and source(bit).

Another table is "**Party**" having columns `partyId`,`party_type`.( It can be 1,2,3.)

> 1. is buyer.
> 2. is seller.
> 3. is witness.

Now what I want is I want to check from **carparties** that there should be at least one party of buyer, one party of seller and one party of witness.

I can check it easily as below pseudo code of SQL.

```
Decalre @isValid as bit = 1
if(select Count(1) 
   From CarParties 
   Inner join partyType on partyType.partyId = CarParties.partyId 
   where car_id=1 and partyType =1 ) > 0
Then
   @isValid = 1
Else
   @isValid =0
```

Like above query i will check for each party and at the end i will select `@isValid`. (You can suggest another way to do it).

Now the twist is, i want to return true if it exists all the parties type with source = 1.
Following are the scenario.

1. Return True if all parties type exist and source is 1.
2. Return False if all parties type exist and source is 0 for any party.
3. Return False if there is no party.
4. Return False if one or two party type exist and any one partytype is missing.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If party_type is limited to (1,2,3) and you want to check if all three are present, it's as easy as SUM:

```
select cp.car_id, sum(distinct p.partytype) 
from @carparties cp join @party p on cp.partyid = p.partyid and p.source = 0
group by cp.car_id 
having sum(distinct p.partytype) = 6
```

(notice I've used SUM(distinct...) to account for possible multiple entries of the same type)

Comment: what if you have 2 "witness" rows but no buyer or seller?  the total would still be 6

Comment: @KM Distinct p.partyType will always give the exact 1 count of one party.
This is a good move by dean. But still have some issue. Trying to reslove it.

Comment: @dean it should be COunt(distinct p.partytype). NOt sum.

Comment: select Count(distinct p.partytype) 
from carparties cp join party p on cp.partyid = p.partyid and p.source = 0
WHere cp.car_id = carId. Working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

You may looking for this

```
DECLARE @isValid AS BIT = 1 
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 
           From CarParties C 
           INNER JOIN partyType  p1 on p1.partyId = C.partyId AND p1.partyType =1
           INNER JOIN partyType  p2 on p2.partyId = C.partyId AND p2.partyType =2
           INNER JOIN partyType  p3 on p3.partyId = C.partyId AND p3.partyType =3
           WHERE car_id=1 and SOURCE = 1)
THEN
  @isValid = 1
Else
  @isValid = 0
```